# One ChartLegend for multiple charts in Dataset?

Tags: graphics, plotting, dataset

Dataset's documentation shows how to leverage GroupBy operator at multiple levels

```
titanic = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}];

titanic[GroupBy[Key["sex"]], GroupBy[Key["class"]], ratio, "survived"]
```

Taking a step further, can generate summary graphics in one line:

```
titanic[GroupBy[Key["sex"]], GroupBy[Key["class"]], 
 Counts /* 
  KeySort /* (PieChart[#, SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}, 
     ChartLegends -> Automatic] &), "survived"]
```

[image]

KeySort insures uniform color assignment to `True` and `False`; without it, some charts will have inverted colors.

Since all charts share the same interpretation, the 6 ChartLegends are redundant.

Is there an option for a single legend to appear, outside the frame of the Dataset?

Wouldn't it be great if the various Chart functions returned associations like `<|"chart"->Graphics[...], "legend"->Graphics[...] |>` that can be more easily processed.

Also, `BarChart[#, ChartLegends->Automatic]` inside Dataset doesn't work, but adding manual values, eg ChartLegends->{"T","F"} works.

Comment: I'm really excited by the prospect of having `Histogram`, `BarChart`, `PieChart` etc operate on nested data in precisely the way you are doing it 'manually' here. And then doing things like choosing the same bins across each category would be totally automatic, as would ensuring there is only one legend, colors are consistent, etc... All of this is possible, and in fact even planned, it just takes time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am still largely mystified by `Dataset` as database querying is alien to me and the `Dataset` internals seem rather opaque, but at least for the given example this appears to be a solution:

```
titanic = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Titanic"}];

panel = titanic[GroupBy[Key["sex"]], GroupBy[Key["class"]], 
   Counts /* KeySort /* (PieChart[#, SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}, 
       ChartLegends -> Automatic] &), "survived"];

Legended[
  panel[[All, All, 1]],
  panel[[1, 1, 2, 1]]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mr.Wizard, this is usable. I looked at PieChart's FullForm to try to extract the legend but saw nested Dynamic and other wrappers and dropped it. Are the panel Parts generic for BarChart, Histogram etc?

Comment: Dataset and Association are atomic for now. Hopefully future versions will allow pattern matching.

Comment: @alancalvitti Apparently it's not truly atomic, though that's the term we've been using.  `Replace` and `ReplaceAll` currently do not work but as you can see `Part` does, and so does `Cases` I believe.  I didn't check to see if this works for other plot types; if it doesn't please let me know and I'll see what can be done about it.

Comment: Part currently only works read only, can't Set. WriteAtomicQ?

Comment: How difficult would it be to modify the built in charts to return Associations with *consistently* named components (main graphics, Legend) and user-named graphics layers? For most tasks I typically build graphics from primitives and am considering similar functionality.

Comment: @alancalvitti Sorry, you're right about `Part`, which I knew but forgot to mention; it supposed to make it into the next point release if I recall correctly.  Returning charts as associations should be too hard I think, assuming a post-processing approach is possible in each case.  Why don't you post a Question about that?